# How to correctly auto scroll to end of scrollbar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am creating a custom chat window and trying to build it completely from scratch. I am very new to front end dev. I come from a backend dev background. So I am learning and applying concepts in parallel.

So far I am able to create the type to chatwindow and the window is auto scrolling to bottom on every addition of new chat message.

However, the auto scrolling works till approximately the first 8-10 messages and then, scroll to bottom breaks and does not work as shown in the attached image:

[image]

Following is the snippet:

```js
function scrollToBottom() {
  $(".scrollContent").animate({
    scrollTop: $(document).height()
  }, "fast");
}
```

```css
/**
  General CSS - Start
*/

body {
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
}

#PageTitle {
  /** background-color: #0295e5; **/
  background-color: #ff6600;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 460px;
  margin-top: 200px;
  margin-left: 200px;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border-color: #0295e5;
  box-shadow: 1px 2px 5px 1px #888888;
}

* {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: normal;
}

.form-control:focus {
  border-color: inherit;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.list-group {
  max-height: 480px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  overflow: scroll;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

.chatboxcontenttile {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.chatboxcontenttile::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

.chatboxcontenttile::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 6px;
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

.chatboxcontenttile::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: #000000;
}


/** CSS for SVG image - Start */

.svg {
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-left: -18px;
}

svg path,
svg circle {
  -webkit-transition: all .1s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .1s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .1s ease;
  -o-transition: all .1s ease;
}

svg:hover path {
  fill: #0295e5;
}


/** CSS for SVG image - End */


/**
  General CSS - End
*/


/**
  Chat Bubble - Start
*/

#bubble_Container {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-color: #0295e5;
  box-shadow: 5px 9px 18px 6px #888888;
  color: white;
  /* Positioning code */
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 50px;
}

#bubble_Container img {
  width: 45px;
  display: block;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

#bubble_Container:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  bottom: 25px;
  right: 50px;
  box-shadow: 5px 9px 18px 10px #888888;
  transition: 200ms;
  -webkit-transition: 200ms;
  fill: red;
}

#bubble_Container:active {
  cursor: pointer;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 50px;
  box-shadow: 5px 9px 18px 6px #888888;
}


/**
  Chat Bubble - End
*/


/**
  Chat Box Container - Start
*/

#chatbox_container_id {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 50px;
  width: 420px;
  height: 600px;
  background-color: white;
  visibility: hidden;
  /* Formattings */
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0px;
  border-color: #e5e3e3;
  box-shadow: 5px 10px 30px 3px #888888;
}


/**
  Chat Box Container - End
*/


/**
  Chat Box Container Title - Start
*/

#ChatboxTitleBlock {
  height: 70px;
}

#ChatboxTitleBlockName {}

#ChatboxTitleBlockName h4 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 45px;
  right: 0;
  top: 20px;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 140px;
  color: #2F80ED;
}

#ChatboxTitleBlockClose {}

#ChatboxTitleBlockCloseButton {
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
}


/**
  Chat Box Container Title - End
*/


/**
  Chat Box Container Content Area - Start
*/

#ChatboxContentBlock {
  height: 480px;
}

.chatboxcontenttile {
  padding: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  clear: both;
}


/** Messaging CSS - Start */


/** sending css **/

.sendMessageRow {
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.sendMessageRow .sendingLastCol {
  padding: 0px;
}

.sendMessageRow .sendingContentBlock {
  padding: 0px;
  margin-left: -10px;
}

.sendingContent p {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  background-color: #2D9CDB;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 16px 14px 16px 14px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  /* fonts */
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 12.5px;
  line-height: normal;
}

.sendMessageRow .sendingThumbnail {
  padding: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-left: 8px;
}

.sendMessageRow .sendingThumbnail img {
  width: 50px;
}


/** reply css **/

.replyMessageRow {
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.replyMessageRow .replyThumbnail {
  padding: 0px;
  margin-left: 28px;
}

.replyMessageRow .replyThumbnail img {
  width: 40px;
}

.replyMessageRow .replyContentBlock {
  padding: 0px;
  margin-left: -28px;
}

.replyContent p {
  display: inline-block;
  background: rgba(227, 235, 244, 0.8);
  color: #6b6a6a;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 15px 14px 15px 14px;
  /* fonts */
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 12.5px;
  line-height: normal;
}

.replyMessageRow .replyLastCol {
  padding: 0px;
}


/** Messaging CSS - End */


/**
  Chat Box Container Content Area - End
*/


/**
  Horizontal Divider - Start
*/

#contentInputDivider {
  margin-top: 0.3rem;
  margin-bottom: 0.3rem;
  border: 1;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}


/**
  Horizontal Divider - End
*/


/**
  Chat Box Container Input - Start
*/

#ChatboxInputBlock {
  margin-top: 2px;
  height: 32px;
}

#ChatboxInputBox {
  margin-top: 1px;
}

#chatBoxInput {
  border: none;
  margin-left: -7px;
  outline: none;
}

#ChatboxVoiceBox {}

#ChatboxSendBox {}


/**
  Chat Box Container Input - End
*/


/**
    SCROLL BAR - Start
*/

.scrollContent {
  width: 420px;
  height: 480px;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 5px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

;
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border-radius: 10px 0px 0px 10px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: rgba(255, 102, 0, 1);
  border-radius: 10px 0px 0px 10px;
}


/**
    SCROLL BAR - End
*/
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Chat box Start -->
<div class="container chatbox_container" id="chatbox_container_id" >

 <!-- Chat box title Start -->
 <div class="row" id="ChatboxTitleBlock">
     <div class="col-sm-11" id="ChatboxTitleBlockName"><h4>A Bot</h4></div>
     <div class="col-sm-1" id="ChatboxTitleBlockClose">
      <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" id="ChatboxTitleBlockCloseButton" >
       <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
   </button>
     </div>
 </div>
 <!-- Chat box title End -->

 <!-- Chat box content area Start -->
 <div class="row" id="ChatboxContentBlock">
    <div class="scrollContent">
     
     <!-- chat messages start -->

     <div class="row replyMessageRow">
      <div class="col-sm-2 replyThumbnail">
       <img src="/images/botimg.png">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-8 replyContentBlock">
       <div class="replyContent">
        <p>How are you?</p>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2 replyLastCol">
       
      </div>
     </div>

     

     <div class="row sendMessageRow">
      <div class="col-sm-2 sendingLastCol">
       
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-8 sendingContentBlock">
       <div class="sendingContent">
        <p>new content ok. Yeah, I agree.</p>
       </div> 
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2 sendingThumbnail">
       <img src="/images/sam.png">
      </div>
     </div>

     <div class="row replyMessageRow">
       <div class="col-sm-2 replyThumbnail">
        <img src="/images/botimg.png">
       </div>
       <div class="col-sm-8 replyContentBlock">
        <div class="replyContent">
         <p>How are you? Yeah, just answering my own question. How is the world now a days? is it yet a better place? I hope so. Yeah, this is just a dummy paragraph.</p>
         
        </div>
       </div>
       <div class="col-sm-2 replyLastCol">
        
       </div>
     </div>

     <div class="row sendMessageRow">
      <div class="col-sm-2 sendingLastCol">
       
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-8 sendingContentBlock">
       <div class="sendingContent">
        <p>new content ok. Yeah, I agree.</p>
       </div> 
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2 sendingThumbnail">
       <img src="/images/sam.png">
      </div>
     </div>

     <div class="row replyMessageRow">
       <div class="col-sm-2 replyThumbnail">
        <img src="/images/botimg.png">
       </div>
       <div class="col-sm-8 replyContentBlock">
        <div class="replyContent">
         <p>How are you?</p>
         
        </div>
       </div>
       <div class="col-sm-2 replyLastCol">
        
       </div>
     </div>

     

     <!-- chat messages end -->

    </div>
   
  

 </div>
 <!-- Chat box content area End -->

 <!-- Divider Start -->
 <hr id="contentInputDivider" />
 <!-- Divider End -->

 <!-- Chat box input area Start -->
 <div class="row" id="ChatboxInputBlock">
  <div class="col-sm-10" id="ChatboxInputBox">
   <input id="chatBoxInput" class="form-control form-control-sm" type="text" placeholder="Type your message here">
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-1" id="ChatboxVoiceBox">
   <img src="/images/ic_mic_24px.svg" class = "svg">
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-1" id="ChatboxSendBox">
   <img src="/images/ic_send_24px.svg" class="svg">
  </div>
  
 </div>
 <!-- Chat box input area End -->
</div>
<!-- Chat box End -->
```

How to properly autoscroll so that the auto scroll to bottom does not break no matter how many messages I type in the chat window?

Comment: where is your css ?

Comment: css is big. Not sure how to put it here. Sorry, I came from a backend dev background where I know how to separate a piece of code and put it is SO. With front end, I am not sure how to put such a big css file. Any recommendations?

Comment: no need to put the whole css sheet here, since you have a `ChatboxContentBlock` div, you can look for the styles related to that div or the child of that div, 
You can create a separate html file and keep adding css until the final result appears, the css are needed in order to actually replicate the issue.

Comment: @Towkir CSS added. Please let me know if I am doing anything stupid. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe the document height is not growing after you add more messages to the chat window. It's hard to tell what is causing it without being able to reproduce your problem. You probably want to set the scrollTop of .scrollContent to a number that is based on that element's height (scrollHeight - offsetHeight)

Comment: whenever you send a message, you'd have to call the `scrollToBottom()` function, did you do it? if so, what happens ?

Comment: yes, I am calling the scrollToBottom() function on every new message and it works perfectly fine. Problem is as I go on sending more messages one after another, after 8 messages, the scroll to bottom does not happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy fix:

```
/**
 *  Auto scroll to bottom
 */
function scrollToBottom() {
    $(".scrollContent").animate({ scrollTop: Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER }, "fast");
}
```

More correct fix, the height of the document is not necessarily the height of the content within the scrollContent, if there is only one child within the ".scrollContent" element, this will work:

```
/**
 *  Auto scroll to bottom
 */
function scrollToBottom() {
    $(".scrollContent").animate({ scrollTop: $(".scrollContent > *").height() }, "fast");
}
```

Comment: Only the first one worked. Could you please explain what it does?

Comment: Just editted my answer, the scrollTop is the amount of pixels the element is scrolled down. 0 is fully scrolled up. For example, if the element ".scrollContent" is 100px in height, and the content is 200px in height. When you scroll the ".scrollContent" element all the way down, the scrollTop() value would be 100 (because all content would be visible). Hope that makes sense!